# Text in TextField invisible when not typing in Android

Tags: codenameone

I have a strange behavior with my codenameone-App running on Android (e.g. 4.2 oder 5.1): The text in a TextField gets invisible, when I stop typing. It gets visible when I continue typing. This does not happen running the App on iOS. I also have this behavior when running the App in an VirtualBox-Installation of Android.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

**Added**: I dont's see this behavior with Android 7.1 running in VirtualBox - but with 4.1 and 5.1 in VirtualBox. And I also don't see the error on the mobile of my son (S5) with Android 4.2.

Comment: Is this something that started recently or you just noticed it now? I think it might be a regression with this fix https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2310

Comment: Please connect a cable to the device and launch DDMS/logcat look at the output when editing and see if there are exceptions or error messages printed out

Comment: When I started to develop my App 12 month ago I had this behavior. Than suddenly it was gone - don't know why. The current Version of the App released in 10/2017 in Google Play store does not have this error. I did some refactoring after this release - but don't have any idea if or why this could be the cause for this error.

Comment: Thanks for the idea to look at Log-Output with DDMS. Never had this idea before... But there is no error or exception logged when editing/typing in the TextArea.

Comment: Can you please file an issue and describe the specific version/model where the text disappears. We'll need to try and reproduce it on our side

Comment: I created an issue on GitHub (https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2317)

Comment: FYI it's best to provide a link back to the source (e.g. this post) so we can have a reference of where this issue came from.